# Curly braces Fatal Errors after PHP 8 update

Tags: php, curly-braces, php-8

I've got a WordPress site that makes heavy use of a plugin, NextEnd Accordion Menu, which is no longer maintained.  It still works great with each new version of WordPress and I'd like to stick to it if possible.  But when I test a site update from PHP 7.3 to 8, the plugin breaks.  Eventually I am going to have to go to PHP 8, so I'm trying to prepare for that time.

I think I've found what needs to be fixed, as in the error logs I see fatal errors--"Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is no longer supported."  When I look at the lines triggering the errors, I can see an easy fix for most of them.

For four out of five of the errors, it's just a matter of changing something like

```
if ($tag{0} == $this->lessc->vPrefix)
```

to

```
if ($tag[0] == $this->lessc->vPrefix)
```

But for the last error the problem is on the elseif line here:

```
protected function end() {
        if ($this->literal(';')) {
            return true;
        } elseif ($this->count == strlen($this->buffer) || $this->buffer{$this->count} == '}') {
            // if there is end of file or a closing block next then we don't need a ;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

That `$this->buffer{$this->count}` seems to be the offending item, but I am way beyond my depth in figuring out how to change it.

I tried changing the curly braces to square braces, to parentheses, to double curly braces, and in each case it just caused more and different errors.

Trying the square braces
`$this->buffer[$this->count]`

Gives me this more complicated and opaque to me new error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: array_merge(): Argument #2 must be of type array, null given in /nas/content/live/stagingsitexray/wp-content/plugins/nextend-accordion-menu/nextend/parse/font.php:27\nStack trace:\n#0 /nas/content/live/stagingsitexray/wp-content/plugins/nextend-accordion-menu/nextend/parse/font.php(27): array_merge(Array, NULL)\n#1 /nas/content/live/stagingsitexray/wp-content/plugins/nextend-accordion-menu/themes/default/default/context.php(39): NextendParseFont->mixinTab('Active')\n#2 /nas/content/live/stagingsitexray/wp-content/plugins/nextend-accordion-menu/library/accordionmenu/menu.php(161): include('/nas/content/li...')\n#3 /nas/content/live/stagingsitexray/wp-content/plugins/nextend-accordion-menu/library/accordionmenu/wordpress/menu.php(67): NextendMenu->addCSS()\n#4 /nas/content/live/stagingsitexray/wp-content/plugins/nextend-accordion-menu/library/accordionmenu/menu.php(56): NextendMenuWordpress->addCSS()\n#5 /nas/content/live/stagingsitexray/wp-content/plugins/nextend-accordion-menu/widget.php(62): NextendMenu->render()\n#6 /nas/content/live/stagingsitexray/wp-includes/class-wp-widget.php(393): NextendAccordionMenuWidget->widget(Array, Array)\n#7 /nas/content/live/stagingsitexray/wp-includes/widgets.php(835): WP_Widget->display_callback(Array, Array)\n#8 /nas/content/live/stagingsitexray/wp-content/themes/customizr/sidebar-left.php(13): dynamic_sidebar('left')\n#9 /nas/content/live/stagingsitexray/wp-includes/template.php(770): require_once('/nas/content/li...')\n#10 /nas/content/live/stagingsitexray/wp-includes/template.php(716): load_template('/nas/content/li...', true, Array)\n#11 /nas/content/live/stagingsitexray/wp-includes/general-template.php(136): locate_template(Array, true, true, Array)\n#12 /nas/content/live/stagingsitexray/wp-content/themes/customizr/inc/czr-front-ccat.php(7650): get_sidebar('left')\n#13 /nas/content/live/stagingsitexray/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(307): CZR_sidebar->czr_fn_render_sidebar('')\n#14 /nas/content/live/stagingsitexray/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(331): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)\n#15 /nas/content/live/stagingsitexray/wp-includes/plugin.php(476): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)\n#16 /nas/content/live/stagingsitexray/wp-content/themes/customizr/index.php(28): do_action('__before_articl...')\n#17 /nas/content/live/stagingsitexray/wp-includes/template-loader.php(106): include('/nas/content/li...')\n#18 /nas/content/live/stagingsitexray/wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once('/nas/content/li...')\n#19 /nas/content/live/stagingsitexray/index.php(17): require('/nas/content/li...')\n#20 {main}\n  thrown in /nas/content/live/stagingsitexray/wp-content/plugins/nextend-accordion-menu/nextend/parse/font.php on line 27, referer: https://stagingsitexray/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page
```

(those are a bunch of other files, not the one I'm currently editing, which is /nas/content/live/stagingsitexray/wp-content/plugins/nextend-accordion-menu/nextend/css/less.php

Comment: I'm not sure why this would be any different from the others - `$this->buffer[$this->count]`. What are the errors you get when you try that? Possibly there's some other unrelated bug that's showing up once you make this first fix.

Comment: Incidentally, if you run the code under PHP 7.4, rather than 8.0, you can get non-fatal deprecation notices for each place the old syntax is used, which might make it easier to find them all in one go. You might see other deprecations and warnings, too, which would help with other sources of errors.

Comment: Thanks! I think you may well be right, but of course that other error is a lot more opaque to me as a beginner.  Here's what using  1[$this-count]` instead of with the curly braces gives me:

Comment: Don't try to paste lots of details into the comment field, click [edit] and add to the original question. Comments are just temporary footnotes, the site is all about the Question and Answer fields.

Comment: Got it.  I'm learning!

Comment: The code provided is irrelevant, as it doesn't contain any `array_merge()` ...or `font.php`.

Comment: I think you've successfully fixed the error. It's just that once PHP gets past that line, something else happens. You're probably better off asking a new question about the error that you don't understand, with the code that triggers that. Do also search for existing questions mentioning that same error message.

Answer (score 0):

replace `$this->buffer{$this->count} == '}'` to `str_ends_with($this->buffer, '}')` or `substr($this->buffer, -1) === '}'`

Comment: That would certainly be more readable. But `$this->buffer[$this->count] == '}'` should work just fine as well (compare https://3v4l.org/fNuFh with https://3v4l.org/HcsC7). The OP's seems to have mistakenly assumed a completely different error is related to this line in some way.

Comment: I think that's exactly what happened.  I thought there was only one type of error, but in fact fixing that one type just led me to others.  Further research/experimentation will be required!